# Evaluate two integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration

I encountered following two integrals
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I_1=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{(x+1)(x+2)(\pi^2+\ln^2x)} \text{d}x\\
&I_2=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{(x+1)(x+2)(\pi^2+\ln^2x)} \text{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
The first one was easier.By contour integration we might have
$$
I_1
=\gamma+\text{Re}\left [ \psi^{(0)}\left (\frac{\ln 2}{2\pi i}   \right )  \right ]
$$
But $I_2$ is individual.Take the substitution $x\to e^{x}$.Then $I_2$ is equal to
$$
I_2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\frac{e^x\ln(1+e^x)}{(e^x+1)(e^x+2)} \frac{\text{d}x}{\pi^2+x^2}
$$
Now I am stuck on this.(My first attempt is too long.)
Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

**Update:**
Using
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t+x} \text{d}t
=\ln\left ( 1+\frac{1}{x}  \right )
$$
Thus we have
$$
I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} \left [ \frac{1}{(t-1)(2t-1)} 
\left ( \frac{1}{\ln t}  -\frac{1}{t-1} \right ) 
+4\left ( 1-\frac{1}{2\ln2}  \right ) \frac{1}{2t-1} 
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{t-1}  
 \right ] \text{d}t
$$
or
$$I_2=
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( 
\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}  }{(e^x-1)(2e^{-x}-1)}
 +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{e^x-1} - \frac{4\left ( 1-\frac{1}{2\ln2}  \right ) }{e^x-2} 
 \right ) \text{d}x$$

---

*Update2*:
First note that
$$
I_2=\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left (1+ \frac{1}{x}   \right ) }
{(x+\frac{1}{2} )(\pi^2+\ln^2x)} \text{d}x}
_{I_3}
-\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left ( 1+\frac{1}{x}  \right ) }
{(x+1)(\pi^2+\ln^2x)} \text{d}x}_{I_4}
$$
And
$$
I_4=I_4=\frac{1}{2} \left(\ln2\pi-1-\gamma\right)
$$
$$
I_3=-2\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}+2-\frac{1}{\ln2}  }
{e^x-2} \text{d}x
$$
And
$$I_2=\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\gamma-\ln2\pi\right)-2\int_{0}^{\infty} 
\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}+2-\frac{1}{\ln2}  }
{e^x-2} \text{d}x$$
**Remark**:This integral related to **"Incomplete polygamma functions"**.It seems like a closed-form.

> **Corollary**
> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\cot x\ln(\cos x)}{x^2+\ln^2(2\cos x)} \text{d}x
> -\pi\int_{0}^{\infty} 
> \frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}+2-\frac{1}{\ln2}  }
> {e^x-2} \text{d}x
> =\frac{\pi}{8} 
> \left (  3+\gamma-7\ln2+3\ln\pi
> +4\text{Re}\left [ \psi^{(0)}\left ( \frac{\ln2}{2\pi i}  \right )  \right ] 
> \right )$$

Comment: Can you add that how did you evaluated the first integral by contour integration

Comment: Please add it such that it would be easier for us to evaluate the second one.